# Find all ordered pairs $(a, b)$ in $a+\frac{10b}{a^2+b^2} = 5\;\;,b+\frac{10a}{a^2+b^2}=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> Find all ordered pairs $(a, b)$ of complex numbers with $a^2+b^2\neq  0,$ and
>
> $\displaystyle a+\frac{10b}{a^2+b^2} = 5\;\;,b+\frac{10a}{a^2+b^2}=4$

$\bf{My\; Solution}::$ Using Complex number..

Given $\displaystyle a+\frac{10b}{a^2+b^2}=5..............(1)$ and $\displaystyle b+\frac{10a}{a^2+b^2}=4...................(2)\times i$

Now Add $\bf{(1)}$ and $\bf{(2)\;,}$ We get

$\displaystyle (a+ib)+\frac{10}{(a+ib)\cdot (a-ib)}\cdot (b+ia) = 5+4i$

So $\displaystyle (a+ib)+\frac{10i\cdot (a-ib)}{(a+ib)\cdot (a-ib)} = 5+4i\Rightarrow (a+ib)+\frac{10i}{(a+ib)}=5+4i$

Now Let $(a+ib)=z\;,$ Then equation is $\displaystyle z+\frac{10i}{z}=5+4i\Rightarrow z^2-(5+4i)z+10i=0$

Now Solving the above equation we get $\displaystyle z = \frac{(5+4i)\pm \sqrt{(5+4i)^2-40i}}{2}=\frac{(5+4i)\pm \sqrt{25-16}}{2}=\frac{(5+4i)\pm 3}{2}=4+2i\;,1+2i$

So $z=x+iy=4+2i\Rightarrow (x,y)=(4,2)$ and $z=x+iy=1+2i\Rightarrow (x,y)=(1,2)$

My Question is , can we solve it without Using Complex number

If yes, The please explain here

Thanks

Comment: We have $$10b=(5-a)(a^2+b^2), 10a=(4-b)(a^2+b^2)$$

On division, $$\frac ba=\frac{5-a}{4-b}\implies a^2-5a=b^2-4b$$

$$\iff4a^2-20a=4b^2-16b\iff(2a-5)^2-(2b-2)^2=9$$

$$\implies2a=3\sec\theta+5,2b=2+3\tan\theta$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy to see that $ab\neq0$.

Thus, our system is equal to
$$(5-a)b=\frac{10b^2}{a^2+b^2}$$ and
$$(4-b)a=\frac{10a^2}{a^2+b^2},$$ which after summing gives
$$(5-a)b+(4-b)a=10$$ or
$$(2a-5)(b-2)=0.$$
The rest is smooth.